# Button to Execute Ruby Without Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

#### Route

```
resources :cars do
  collection do
    get :f01a
  end
end
```

#### Controller

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def f01a
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @count = Count.find_by_user_id(@user)
    @count.increment!(:f02)
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

#### View

```
<%= button_to "add f01", f01a_cars_path %>
```

I can't get this to work. I need to execute this code from a button.

Comment: What do you expect the button to execute? The controller action `f01a`? What does "not working" mean? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm getting No route matches [POST] "/foods/f01a" error. I just want the button to execute the 4 lines in the f01a action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button_to` sends a POST request, but your routing is setup to only accept GET requests. You should change it to:

```
resources :cars do
  collection do
    post :f01a
  end
end
```

Since you're using `params[:id]` in your action, but not sending it in at all, you'll need to pass it in your `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "add f01", f01a_cars_path(:id => something)
```

(Replace `something` with whatever ID you want to pass.)

Comment: The third parameter for [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) is `html_options`. Shouldn't it be `<%= button_to "add f01", f01a_cars_path(:id => something) %>` or something?

Comment: Got it to work, thanks for the help.    <%= button_to "add f01", f01a_users_path(:id => @user.id) %>

Comment: If it's acting on a single car wouldn't it be more-usual to have this on a member instead of a collection? (I know the OP has it on a collection, but OP likely doesn't know better.)

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought about that at first, but the ID is being used to find a User, not a Car. It should probably be renamed to `user_id` to reduce confusion. It's also questionable why an action in CarsController does nothing with Car.